# Using the idiom "give a heads up"

Tags: idioms

I have seen many people using the idiom give a heads up to notify or inform that something is going to happen.

Can I also use "get a heads up" to get an update or progress of work, project etc.

For example, "Could I get a heads up on the update of this project?"

Thank you

Comment: You might say "Could you give me a heads up if XXX is about to happen?", but your proposed request appears to simply be asking for an update on an update.

Comment: You could ask for a heads up on the progress of the project. Heads up is more of a warning of a problem, rather than a standard update.

Comment: @YosefBaskin - Asking for a "heads up" on the report's progress is still just asking for a progress report.  A "heads up" is a reasonably spontaneous warning of something about to happen.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate but http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17981/where-did-the-idiom-giving-a-heads-up-come-from has info for the OP

Comment: Rather more frequently used in America than in Britain, I would suggest. It may explain why it is not universally understood.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily mean that something is going to happen. It is a notification; that's all. But it is typically a notification that something is happening now or is about to happen, or that something has been completed or its completion status (a status report).

Comment: Understand that a "heads up" is a form of alarm.  Simply asking for a report is not asking for a "heads up".  In essence, if "Give me a heads up" is not followed by "if" or "when" then the phrase is being used incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, the metaphor is from something literally being about to hit someone and you shout "heads up" to alert someone to look up so they'll see it. You wouldn't give a heads up on progress on a project, but you might give a heads up on an unexpected delay to it.

Comment: This is used quite frequently in London, Britain, where I live and work. It can be used in either way. To inform or be informed. It literally means someone got you to look up from your current work and notice something incoming.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking for someone to characterize the progress of something they're working on, it wouldn't make a whole lot of sense to ask for a 'heads up' on the status of the project. As other commenters have noted, the act of giving someone a 'heads up' on something is more of an action of warning them or giving them notice of something about to come. If you were asking them to give you a heads up when the update is about to be finished, that would make sense, but that doesn't seem to be what you're asking here.

Answer (score 0):

**heads up** [tfd](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/heads-up)

> adj. Showing an alert, competent style: play heads-up basketball
>   n. Informal - Information or notification: gave me a heads-up on the new
>   security measures.

It can be an alert ... or just a notification.  My sense is:

> Yes, you can get a heads up on the *update* [i would substitute
>   *status*] of this project.